# Sony Bravia JavaScript API & Emulator

Tags: javascript, sdk, television, sony

I recently purchased a Sony Bravia TV that comes with Internet capability built in.  It supports a number of internet capable widgets and web video streaming apps for sites like youtube, twitter & various yahoo! offerings. I'd like to hack on the SDK, but the only version I can find is Japanese.

Is there an English version of the SDK?
Where can I find some tutorials/examples?

- [Japanese SDK Documentation (English Layout & JavaScript API pdfs included)](http://www.jp.sonystyle.com/Taiken/Original/Applicast/download.html)

Comment: Did you manage to find an English SDK?

Comment: no, I gave up on it after my tv power supply died. I'm waiting to see what happens with android & apple TV before I buy something new and start hacking again...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at this specification https://dlx.jp.sonystyle.com/dlx/nws/vgc/taiken/applicast/AC-JavaScriptAPISpec.pdf, hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, it looks promising.

Comment: I cannot download it, can you upload it again? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Check out this site: http://www.geekpage.jp/web/AppliCast/ (Japanese.)  It has examples, links and other items that look useful.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think they released the SDK outside Japan. You might have good chance with Chrome and its built in Google Translate to navigate your self into the Japanese documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I tried chrome to view the page like you suggested, that's a nice feature.

I'm still looking for any more info out there beyond this page...

Answer (score 0):

As I know the SONY Bravia is the only major TV series that does not have any SDK...

Or are there any newer information about that?

BR
STeN